# How can I draw a random term from a Lucene index?

Tags: lucene, statistics, nlp

I would like to draw terms at random, distributed as they are in the original text.  In other words, if the word "elephant" occurs twice as often as the word "hippopotamus" in all the indexed documents, it should occur twice as often in my random draw.  This should be done in an efficent manner.

It seems to me as if the index may not be an ideal data structure for this, but it is seductive: it has all the terms, and their frequencies.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Frequencies of lucene unigrams and bigrams](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582572/frequencies-of-lucene-unigrams-and-bigrams)

Comment: You need a Unigram distribution, I've voted to close as a duplicate of a question with answers that explain how.

Comment: I agree - thanks for the pointer - it didn't come up when I searched using what seemed like natural queries to me